# Counterexample for subgraphs of a graph to be a bi-Heyting algebra, not a Boolean algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

*The lattice of subgraphs of a graph form a co-Heyting Algebra.*

This is what written in my textbook. However I doubt it, because if I think as follows, it seems to be a Boolean algebra. So what is wrong in my plot? Could give me a counterexample to show the lattice is not a Boolean but a co-Heyting algebra? (Note: It also forms a Heyting algebra, then collectively a bi-Heyting algebra. But I just talk about the co-Heyting side for simplicity.)

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ s.t. $E\subseteq V\times V$,
let $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2,E_2)$ be subgraphs of $G$, i.e. $V_1,V_2\subseteq V$ and $E_1,E_2\subseteq E$.
Also we assume that *graph union*: $G_1\cup G_2=(V_1\cup V_2,E_1\cup E_2)$.

The co-pseudo-complement $\sim G_1$ is by definition the smallest element such that $G_1\cup \sim G_1 = G$.
I have a hypothesis that $\sim G_1$ can be equivalently obtained by $\sim G_1 = ( (V \setminus V_1)\cup {\bf proj}_1(E\setminus E_1)\cup {\bf proj}_2(E\setminus E_1), E\setminus E_1)$ $ \cdots (\ast)$.
If my hypothesis is correct, it means that we *always* have the co-pseudo-complement for every subgraph of the given graph $G$, and therefore, the lattice is a Boolean algebra.

If I consider in this way above, I get a wrong conclusion that the lattice of subgraphs of a graph forms a Boolean algebra. I know that a Boolean algebra is a special case of a Heyting algebra, so the statement in the first line of this question is nothing wrong, but I'm afraid that my conclusion is too strong.

So what is wrong in my idea? Is the hypothesis $(\ast)$ wrong?

Comment: If you have a question about something you read in a book, ***WHY WON'T YOU TELL US WHAT BOOK IT IS???*** If this were a car forum and you had a problem with your car, would you leave the make, model, and year out of your question?

Comment: I guess you count the "null graph" $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ as a graph, otherwise you don't even get a lattice. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I count the null graph as a subgraph of the given graph $G$. Also I'm sorry that I didn't provide the information about the book. I'll give it tomorrow. But I found not only one but also at least 3 books and 2 papers mention the same.

Comment: How many subgraphs does $K_2$ (complete graph with two vertices, one edge) have? I count $5$ of them, including the null graph (no vertices), but I don't know of any $5$-element Boolean algebra.

Comment: If you remove the edge from $K_2$ you get a subgraph $H=2K_1$ (two isolated vertices) which has no complement in the lattice of subgraphs; every proper subgraph of $K_2$ is a subgraph of $H.$

Comment: I just notice that you describe the edge set as $E\subseteq V\times V.$ So your "graphs" are actually digraphs? I don't see how that will help. if $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{1,2\}$ and $E=\{(1,2)\}$ (two vertices and one directed edge) I still get $5$ subgraphs counting the null graph.